# Using ActiveAdmin's status_tag in a link_to method causing the tag to render twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've been running into some unexpected behavior attempting to create a hyperlink using the `link_to` helper with the ActiveAdmin `status_tag`. Passing a `status_tag` to the `link_to` method is causing the tag to render twice.

Specifically, if you have an ActiveAdmin resource, call it Foo.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo do
  index do
     column "Bar" do |hh|
        link_to status_tag('test', label: 'testing', class: 'error'), edit_admin_bar_path(hh.bar)
     end
  end
end
```

This produces the following html within the index table:

```
<td class="col col-bar">
  <span class="status_tag test error">testing</span>
    <a href="/admin/bar/1/edit">                          
       <span class="status_tag test error">testing</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/components/status_tag.rb) for `status_tag`, I can't help but wonder if its rendering the tag when it calls `super` in the build method, along with returning the [ActiveAdmin::Views::StatusTag](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/Views/StatusTag#build-instance_method) when its complete and passing that value then to `link_to`. But I'm not entirely sure.

I couldn't find any other questions related to this issue or anything specific to this on Google. Is this a side effect of some desired behavior? Or is this use case not what one of these methods was designed for?

I'm using:

- activeadmin (1.0.0.pre2 0ac35b7)
- Rails 4.2.5.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround could be to wrap the status_tag into a new Arbre context. That should avoid the tag to be written directly on the main context

Something like this:

`link_to Arbre::Context.new { status_tag('test', label: 'testing', class: 'error') }, edit_admin_bar_path(hh.bar)`

I know...it looks ugly! But you can put into a Rails helper or code it as an Arbre component.